# Trying to get vaules from a posted list, but I keep getting 0 for all values

Tags: php, loops

```
<?php

//LOOP

$marigold = 0;

$rose = 0;

$tulip = 0;

for ($y = 0; $i < 5; $y++) { // The loop top limit is 5 because there are 5 objects with ids: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

    $value = $_POST[$y];

    if ($value == "marigold") $marigold++;

    if ($value == "rose") $rose++;

    if ($value == "tulip") $tulip++;

};

echo "Marigold";

echo "<span id='marigold'> $marigold</span>";

echo "<br>";

echo "Rose";

echo "<span id='rose'> $rose</span>";

echo "<br>";

echo "Tulip";

echo "<span id='tulip'> $tulip</span>";

?>
```

Comment: You might be better off changing your for loop to `foreach($_POST as $value)`. You can also `var_dump($_POST);` before or after your loop, and `var_dump($value);` inside the loop to double-check your values.

Comment: What's actually posted to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have the ini setting "display_errors" set to off. Because this line `for ($y = 0; $i < 5; $y++)` would be giving an "Undefined variable" error. There is no `$i`.  Perhaps set display_errors on (something like `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`), or at least look in the php error log to see if this program is reporting errors. There's no such thing as too much feedback.